# Prove that the following function has a branch cut

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

I am given with a function $$\zeta(z)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\mathrm{d}x \frac{f(x)}{z-x}.$$ Any idea to prove that $\zeta(z)$ is discontinuous across real axis for $f(x)\neq 0$?

Comment: for what kind of $f$ ?

Comment: I do not know what exactly is $f$. All I am interested is to prove the discontinuity for $f(x)\neq 0$.

Comment: what about $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{e^{ix}}{(x+i)^2}$ ? if I'm not wrong, we get $\zeta(z) = -2 i \pi f(z)$ by closing the contour with the upper half-circle and applying the Cauchy integral formula

Comment: That might be okay. But, what I am really interested is to carry out the proof without any specific functional form. This should be possible as in the real axis, $z-x$ vanishes at some $x=z$, and therefore, the integral diverges as long as $f(x)\neq 0$. I am not sure how to write this systematically.

Comment: @user1952009, how does that help anyways in proving the discontinuity?

Comment: I don't understand. of course, we need $\frac{f(x)}{x+i}$ to be integrable. but the integral is not well-defined when $z \in \mathbb{R}$. then, how do you define $\zeta(z)$ when $z$ is real ?

Comment: Exactly, the integral is not defined when $z$ is real. This fact should be related to the discontinuity.

Comment: I think I understood. do you know the [Cauchy integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) ? do you know how to prove that with $F(z) = \int_{|s|=1} \frac{g(s)}{s-z} ds$ then $F(z)$ is defined for any complex number $|z| \ne 1$, and it is $C^\infty$ for $|z| > 1$ and for $|z| <1$, but these are two different functions which don't coincide everywhere when $|z|\to 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z=x+iy\;$   with $\;y>0$, then 
\begin{align}
\zeta(z)&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \frac{f(t)}{z-t}dt\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \frac{(x-t)f(t)}{(x-t)^2+y^2}dt-i\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \frac{yf(t)}{(x-t)^2+y^2}dt.
\end{align}

We recall Poisson's integral for the half plane:
Theorem.  Assume that $f(t)$ is piecewise continuous and bounded for all real $t$,$$
P_f(z)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \frac{yf(t)}{(x-t)^2+y^2}dt$$
represents a harmonic function in the upper half plane with boundary values $\lim_{y\to +0}P_f(z)=f(x)$ at points of continuity.

By this theorem we have $$
\lim_{y\to +0} \zeta(z)=I_f(x) -i\pi f(x) 
$$
if $f$ is continuous at $x$ and the limit $$I_f(x)=\lim_{y\to 0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \frac{(x-t)f(t)}{(x-t)^2+y^2}dt$$ exists.

Now we consider $\lim_{y\to -0}\zeta(z)$. When $y<0$, 
\begin{align}
\zeta(z)&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \frac{f(t)}{z-t}dt\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \frac{(x-t)f(t)}{(x-t)^2+y^2}dt+i\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \frac{(-y)f(t)}{(x-t)^2+y^2}dt\\
&\to I_f(x)+i\pi f(x) \quad (\,y<0,\, y\to 0\,), 
\end{align}
since $$
\lim_{y\to -0} \int_{-\infty}^\infty  \frac{(-y)f(t)}{(x-t)^2+y^2}dt= \lim_{\xi\to +0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \frac{\xi f(t)}{(x-t)^2+\xi^2}dt=\pi f(x).$$
Thus we see that
$$\lim_{y\to -0}\zeta(z)=\lim_{y\to +0}\zeta(z)+2i\pi f(x),$$ 
which implies that $\zeta (z)$ is discontinuous across the real axis.